# How to fill the screen in a nasm os

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, bios, osdev

I am currently making my own custom os in nasm and i am trying to make an error screen. So i need to fill the screen with red. This is my 16bit code so far.

```
sysError:
    mov cx, 24 ;empty lines
    .loop:
    call printNL
    loop .loop
    mov ah, 0x02 ;set cursor
    mov bh, 0x00 ;page 0
    mov dh, 0x00 ;0th row
    mov dl, 0x00 ;0th char
    mov bl, 17h
    int 0x10 ;set cursor
    pop cx
    add cx, (skip_NL-main_loop)
    push cx
    ;fill with red here
    mov si, errorSTR
    call printString
    jmp hang
    hang:
        jmp hang
```

It clears the screen and prints the error message to the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Int 10h/AH=6](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0096.htm) to scroll the window up and effectively have the BIOS clear the screen in a specified foreground and background color. A simple bootloader that clears the screen with bright white on red would be:

```
TEXTMODE_NUM_ROWS EQU 25
TEXTMODE_NUM_COLS EQU 80

; EGA Color Palette can be found here:
;    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Graphics_Adapter#Color_palette
COLOR_RED          EQU 4
COLOR_BRIGHT_WHITE EQU 15

org 0x7c00

main:    
    xor ax, ax                 ; DS=ES=0x0000
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax                 ; SS:SP = 0x0000:0x7c00 (grow down beneath bootloader)
    mov sp, 0x7c00
    cld                        ; DF=0 forward string instruction movement

    ; http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0096.htm
    ; Int 0x10
    ; AH = 06h
    ; AL = number of lines by which to scroll up (00h = clear entire window)
    ; BH = attribute used to write blank lines at bottom of window
    ; CH,CL = row,column of window's upper left corner
    ; DH,DL = row,column of window's lower right corner    
    mov ax, 0x0600             ; AH = 6 = Scroll Window Up, AL = 0 = clear window
    mov bh, COLOR_RED << 4 | COLOR_BRIGHT_WHITE
                               ; Attribute to clear screen with (White on Red)
    xor cx, cx                 ; Clear window from 0, 0
    mov dx, TEXTMODE_NUM_ROWS << 8 | TEXTMODE_NUM_COLS
                               ; Clear window to 24, 80
    int 0x10                   ; Clear the screen

    mov ah, 0x02               ; Set cursor
    mov bh, 0x00               ; Page 0
    mov dx, 0x00               ; Row = 0, Col = 0
    int 0x10

    cli
.endloop:
    hlt
    jmp .endloop

TIMES 510-($-$$) db 0x00       ; Pad Boot sector to 510 bytes
dw 0xaa55                      ; Boot signature
```

Alternatively you can clear the display by writing a space character and an attribute to every cell on the screen by directly writing to the text video memory at 0xb800:0x0000. Physical address 0xb8000 is where page 0 of text video memory starts. The code could look like:

```
TEXTMODE_NUM_ROWS EQU 25
TEXTMODE_NUM_COLS EQU 80
TEXTMODE_VID_SEG  EQU 0xb800

; EGA Color Palette can be found here:
;    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Graphics_Adapter#Color_palette
COLOR_RED          EQU 4
COLOR_BRIGHT_WHITE EQU 15

org 0x7c00

main:
    xor ax, ax                 ; DS = 0x000
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax                 ; SS:SP = 0x0000:0x7c00 (grow down beneath bootloader)
    mov sp, 0x7c00
    cld                        ; DF=0 forward movement

    mov bx, TEXTMODE_VID_SEG
    mov es, bx                 ; ES = Text video memory segment
    xor di, di                 ; DI = 0x0000 offset to upper left of display (page 0)
    mov ax, (COLOR_RED << 4 | COLOR_BRIGHT_WHITE) << 8 | ' '
                               ; Attribute to clear screen with (White on Red)
                               ; Clear with ' ' space character
    mov cx, TEXTMODE_NUM_ROWS * TEXTMODE_NUM_COLS
                               ; CX = number of screen cells (words) to clear
    rep stosw                  ; Clear the display a word at a time

    mov ah, 0x02               ; Set cursor
    mov bh, 0x00               ; Page 0
    mov dx, 0x00               ; Row = 0, Col = 0
    int 0x10

    cli
.endloop:
    hlt
    jmp .endloop

TIMES 510-($-$$) db 0x00       ; Pad Boot sector to 510 bytes
dw 0xaa55                      ; Boot signature
```